# Serilaizer is creating a new object instead of editing an existing one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like the following :

```
class PutAwayProductsPositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PutAwayProductsPosition
        fields = "__all__"


class PutAwaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_position = PutAwayProductsPositionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PutAway
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('products_position', [])
        prdcts = []
        for item in items_objects:
            i = PutAwayProductsPosition.objects.create(**item)
            prdcts.append(i)
        instance = PutAway.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print("prdcts", prdcts)
        instance.products_position.set(prdcts)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('products_position', [])
        print("items_objects in update", items_objects)
        prdcts = []
        for item in items_objects:
            kp_instance, created = PutAwayProductsPosition.objects.update_or_create(pk=item.get('id'), defaults=item)
            prdcts.append(kp_instance.pk)
        instance.products_position.set(prdcts)
        instance = super(PutAwaySerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

When I try to edit a particular object this update_or_create always creates a new entry.
I checked for the error by printing the validated data and it seems the serilaizer is not validating the `id` field despite the serilizer's model being set to "**all**"
How do I solve this ?

The data I get from serliazer is the following :

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "products_position": [
        {
            "id": 297,
            "put_position": "F.G.H.I.J",
            "is_put": true,
            "products": 312
        },
        {
            "id": 298,
            "put_position": "F.G.H.I.J",
            "is_put": true,
            "products": 310
        },
        {
            "id": 299,
            "put_position": "F.G.H.I.J",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 310
        },
        {
            "id": 300,
            "put_position": "F.G.H.I.J",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 310
        },
        {
            "id": 301,
            "put_position": "F.G.H.I.J",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 310
        },
        {
            "id": 302,
            "put_position": "F.G.H.I.J",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 310
        },
        {
            "id": 303,
            "put_position": "A.B.C.D.E",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 311
        },
        {
            "id": 304,
            "put_position": "A.B.C.D.E",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 311
        },
        {
            "id": 305,
            "put_position": "A.B.C.D.E",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 309
        },
        {
            "id": 306,
            "put_position": "A.B.C.D.E",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 309
        },
        {
            "id": 307,
            "put_position": "A.B.C.D.E",
            "is_put": false,
            "products": 309
        }
    ],
    "putaway_id": 0,
    "completely_executed": false,
    "partially_executed": false,
    "created": "2023-04-04T10:33:11.701963Z",
    "scheduled_datetime": "2023-04-04T10:33:11.702064Z",
    "warehouse": 60,
    "grn": 520,
    "employee_assigned": 111,
    "owner": 93
}
```

items_objects in Validated Data:

```
[OrderedDict([('put_position', 'F.G.H.I.J'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (312)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'F.G.H.I.J'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (310)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'F.G.H.I.J'), ('is_put', True), ('products', <Product: Product object (310)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'F.G.H.I.J'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (310)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'F.G.H.I.J'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (310)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'F.G.H.I.J'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (310)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'A.B.C.D.E'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (311)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'A.B.C.D.E'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (311)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'A.B.C.D.E'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (309)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'A.B.C.D.E'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (309)>)]), OrderedDict([('put_position', 'A.B.C.D.E'), ('is_put', False), ('products', <Product: Product object (309)>)])]
```

Models:

```
class PutAwayProductsPosition(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    put_position = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    is_put = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class PutAway(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grn = models.ForeignKey("grn.GRN", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_assigned = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    putaway_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    products_position = models.ManyToManyField(PutAwayProductsPosition)
    completely_executed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    partially_executed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    scheduled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Could you share your models?

Comment: @Niko Updated the question with models

Answer (score 0):

Read-only fields are not passed internally to validated_data, this is the intentional behavior of drf, details can be found in this [ticket](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2320).

Try to add extra_kwargs to `Meta` in `PutAwayProductsPositionSerializer` to set `read_only` property for `id` field to `False`

```
class PutAwayProductsPositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PutAwayProductsPosition
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs  = {'id': {'read_only': False},}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I give you a solution, I must say that the endpoint is a little bit weird. Usually in nested relations you would want to code another endpoint with an [`extra action`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing), which would make you code more organized and improve the management of your nested objects, something like:

```py
http://localhost:8000/putaway/{pk}/products_position
```

Related to your problem, as you noted, the issue is that you do not get an `id` in `validated_data` and since it is `None` then it will create a new object. For now I cannot give you a concrete answer why (probably because `.update` does not support modifications of nested objects)

One solution would be to use `request.data` objects and pass it to the serializer as an [`extra context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) by overriding `.update` method on your `ViewSet`:

views.py

```py
class PutAwayViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PutAway.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PutAwaySerializer

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        products_position = request.data.get('products_position', None)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            instance,
            data=request.data,
            partial=partial,
            context={'products_position': products_position}
        )

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```py
class PutAwaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_position = PutAwayProductsPositionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PutAway
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        items_data = self.context.get('products_position')
        item_objects = instance.products_position.all()
        if items_data:
            for obj in items_data:
                obj['products'] = Product.objects.get(pk=obj['products'])
                pp_instance, created = PutAwayProductsPosition.objects.update_or_create(pk=obj['id'], defaults=obj)

                if not item_objects.filter(id=pp_instance.id).exists():
                    instance.products_position.add(pp_instance)

        return instance
```

If you are commiting to this method I would advise to use the same process for `.create`.